# How to implement efficient seach functionality if search parameters needs to be computed dynamically?

Tags: performance, search, dynamic, time-series, computation

We have time series data for a financial instrument and lots of computation can be done using time series data for an instrument.Users can select those computations as search criteria and get desired search results. However,we cannot store all the computation in database, as each instrument can have almost 5000 calculations. We store couple of calculations in database,but not all. For example: user can select exponential moving avg. and than can specify any numerical value(5,10,15,20 etc.) for computing it.User can than specify filter for exponential moving avg. > or < than or = some value. This means we have to compute those parameters before applying filter and present results to the user. Running computations on the fly behind search and than filter takes lot of time and give inferior performance. Also, different users can select different computation as search criteria. This at times bombards our services and search times goes above 15 mins. What is best way to design such system. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: no response to this from 2 days. please help. looking for suggetions

Comment: great. thank you. i heard great thing about stack overflow and thought will get some advice. however, i m not sure whether nobody is here to advice or i need to rephrase my question.